# CakePHP 4: How to add count of association results to where conditions

Tags: mysql, cakephp, count, query-builder, cakephp-4.x

I'm trying to add the count results of an association to the where conditions, for example:

```php
$findQuery = $this->Products->find('all');

$findQuery->leftJoinWith('Synonyms', function($q) {
    return $q->where(['Synonyms.title LIKE' => '%TEST%']);
});
$findQuery->select([
    'amount_of_matching_synonyms' => $findQuery->func()->count('Synonyms.id')
]);
$findQuery->where([
    'OR' => [
        'Products.description LIKE' => '%TEST%',
        'amount_of_matching_synonyms >' => 0
    ]
]);
```

What happens now is that I'm getting 1 result returned with the 'amount_of_matching_synonyms' field. But this appears to have a cumulated result of all the records it should return.

Please help me out!

Answer (score 1):

You should first figure out how to do these things in plain SQL, it will then be much easier to translate things to the query builder.

Counting related data requires joining in the realted data and creating groups on which aggregate functions can be used, and you're missing the latter. Furthermore you cannot use aggregates in the `WHERE` clause, as grouping happens after the `WHERE` clause is applied, you would have to use the `HAVING` clause instead.

The basic SQL to filter on such counting would look something like this:

```sql
SELECT
    COUNT(synonyms.id) amount_of_matching_synonyms
FROM
    products
LEFT JOIN
    synonyms ON synonyms.id = synonyms.product_id
GROUP BY
    products.id
HAVING
    amount_of_matching_synonyms > 0
```

Translating this into the query builder would be fairly simple, you'd just need `group()` and `having()`, something like this:

```php
$findQuery = $this->Products
    ->find()
    ->select([
        'Products.description',
        'amount_of_matching_synonyms' => $findQuery->func()->count('Synonyms.id')
    ])
    ->leftJoinWith('Synonyms', function(\Cake\ORM\Query $q) {
        return $q->where(['Synonyms.title LIKE' => '%TEST%']);
    })
    ->group('Products.id')
    ->having([
        'OR' => [
            'Products.description LIKE' => '%TEST%',
            'amount_of_matching_synonyms >' => 0
        ],
    ]);
```

Note that you need to select the description, otherwise the condition in the having clause would fail.

The resulting SQL would look something like this:

```sql
SELECT
    products.description,
    COUNT(synonyms.id) amount_of_matching_synonyms
FROM
    products
LEFT JOIN
    synonyms ON
        synonyms.product_id = products.id
        AND
        synonyms.title LIKE '%TEST%'
GROUP BY
    products.id
HAVING
    products.description LIKE '%TEST%'
    OR
    amount_of_matching_synonyms > 0
```

See also

- **[MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual / Functions and Operators / Aggregate Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/aggregate-functions-and-modifiers.html)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Aggregates - Group and Having](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#aggregates-group-and-having)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Subqueries](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#subqueries)**